# SQL Server express backup

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

Can I use a SQL Server Express database backup file to restore that database on a full fledged version of SQL Server. I am particularly looking at SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets be clear about one thing first, SQL Server Express , Standard and Enterprise are the Editions.

SQL Server 2005 , 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 are SQL Server versions.

Now coming to your question whether you can restore a database from 2008 Express to 2012 Enterprise?

The Simple Answer would be YES you can.

A couple of things to keep in mind.

1. SQL Server Editions has no limitation you can backup and restore databases from one Edition to another without any restrictions (Except SQL Server Express which can only accommodate databases upto 10 GB). Other than this size limitation in SQL Server express, all is good.
2. Whereas SQL Server Versions has a very strict limitation, You can go up 3 versions but cannot go down at all.

For example if you had taken a backup on SQL Server 2008 (regardless of Edition) you can restore this backup onto a SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2 , 2012 and I think also on 2014. But you cannot restore this onto a SQL Server 2005.

I hope the explanation clears some confusions.

Comment: Thanks. I found that my problem was that the backup types on the databases were not set to full. And I had to script out the restore. The gui would not recognize the files (2012) for some reason.